# EasyMock 3.2: How to address public variables in a mocked class?

Tags: easymock

I'm trying to mock an open-source class. That class uses a number of public variables instead of get methods. I need to have the mocked class return another mocked class when that variable is accessed, but I'm not sure how. Here's an example:

```
SolrQueryRequest request = createNiceMock(SolrQueryRequest.class);
...
replay(request);

ResponseBuilder builder = createNiceMock(ResponseBuilder.class);
expect(builder.req).andReturn(request); // Throws exception
replay(builder);
```

The above example, however, throws the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available` on the `builder.req` line. Any idea how I can do this? Please note I don't have the option of refactoring the mocked classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after playing around with it more I discovered it was pretty easy:

```
myBuilder.req = request;
```

Now when my class under test accesses the `myBuilder.req` variable, it is correctly set to my mocked `SolrQueryRequest`.